# Best approach to replace min-date with empty string in asp.net (3.5)?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, data-binding, mindate

I am using a repeater and have the following code, it return 1/1/0001 when responseDateDue (DateTime) is null from database:

```
 <td><b>Response Due</b><br /><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ResponseDateDue","{0:d}") %></td>
```

I thought about wrapping it with a public function ReplaceMinDate(X) to return an empty string for mindate. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Have you looked at `DateTime?` (`Nullable<DateTime>`)?

Comment: Yeah, I should have used it in the beginning ...it would have saved  me all this work.

Comment: Thanks you Tim for the help!